# Change the logic of hashing the images

Tags: media-library

I would like to change the logic of the image hashing. Because our `width` and `height` parameters directly in the url. As I checked the `HashingUtils` class it does not look to easy to change without any risk because it can be used any other assemblies and I already found 3 places where it is used in the Sitecore.Kernel assembly. The problem is that the default implementation only deal with querystring parameters.

For example the url should like this:

```
/images/{22EB368A-4AD3-48C8-B1EB-1BC14DE0F7BF}-200-100.jpg?hash=AE8EB10933E68E98C9C65324F9CDF0FA2D3AEBAA
```

And I would like to generate the hash from the part of the url. In this case from `200` and `100`.

I already implemented a custom MediaProvider which is resolving the media item by ID, width and height. Actually the resolving done by a composite key `[ID]-[width]-[height]`.

Comment: Can you explain your problem more detailed. Probably by adding a url example of what it is now and what you would like it to be

Comment: Crossing the river to get water. The width and height parameters are exactly the reason hashing is done to begin with - to prevent DOS attacks by creating a million differently scaled versions of images in your media cache.

Comment: @MarkCassidy true. That's why I want to generate the hash from the width and height. The only difference is that these parameters are not in the querystring, they are part of the path.

Comment: I don't get it then. If you make them part of the path, they become publicly accessible. No?

Comment: @MarkCassidy If the hash is a checksum of the values in the URL a filter would reject any requests where the hash does not match, thereby preventing the scenario you're talking about.  This obviously assumes it's not possible to generate the hash from outside the environment or all is lost.  I suggest salting with the app's MachineKey or a manual appSetting salt.  If you want at the machineKey use the first 64 bytes of the `HttpApplication.s_autogenKeys` byte array (.Net 4.5 only).

Comment: *UPDATE:* Turns out the `HashingUtils::ComputeHash()` method @Dmytro mentions below already includes a salt that is stored in the Sitecore setting `Settings.Media.RequestProtection.SharedSecret`, so that should be sufficient, assuming you remembered to change it from its default value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution

`HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(string url)` and `HashingUtils.GetAssetUrlHash(string url)` take the full URL path into account when generating the hash. So there are no adjustments in the algorithm that you need to make.

Just use this code:

```
string imageUrl = // get the URL
imageUrl = HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(imageUrl);
```

This is all you need to generate a URL with an added hash value.

---

## Proof

Here's the (reformatted) source code of `HashingUtils.GetAssetUrlHash()`:

```
public static string GetAssetUrlHash(string url)
{
    url = url.ToLowerInvariant();

    UrlString urlString = new UrlString(url);

    if (!HashingUtils.Proxy.IsMediaUrl(url))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    Uri result;
    string urlPath = (Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out result) ? result.LocalPath : urlString.Path).TrimStart('/');

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    stringBuilder.Append(string.Format("{0}?", urlPath));

    for (int i = 0; i < MediaManager.Config.RequestProtection.QueryParametersToProtect.Count; i++)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append(
            string.Format(
                "{0}={1}",
                MediaManager.Config.RequestProtection.QueryParametersToProtect[i],
                urlString.Parameters[MediaManager.Config.RequestProtection.QueryParametersToProtect[i]]));

        if (i < MediaManager.Config.RequestProtection.QueryParametersToProtect.Count - 1)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append("&");
        }
    }

    return HashingUtils.ComputeHash(stringBuilder.ToString());
}
```

As you can see, the URL path *is* used when creating the hash. It's appended to the `stringBuilder`:

```
stringBuilder.Append(string.Format("{0}?", urlPath));
```

The `urlPath` here will be equal to `/images/{22EB368A-4AD3-48C8-B1EB-1BC14DE0F7BF}-200-100.jpg` in your example.